# Confusion regarding the first principle to find derivative of a function.

Tags: limits

Let me take an arbitrary function f which is continuous and differentiable wherever defined. 
 According to the first principle, $f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$.
Also, $f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h}$.   
However, if I were to replace $x$ with $x+h$ and say $f'(x+h)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+2h)-f(x+h)}{h}$ it would be wrong. 
An example would be to take $sin(x+h)$, by using compound angle formulae we would get $cos(x+3h/2)$.  So why exactly is it wrong to say $f'(x+h)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+2h)-f(x+h)}{h}$?

Comment: What does it mean replace $x$ with $x+h$ when $h$ is a local variable inside the limit? You can replace $x$ with $x+g$ for some new $g$, this would be just a simple substitution and everything works.

Comment: What is the first principle?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I believe it is also called the delta method to find derivative, I was taught that it is called first principle, you can refer to this https://brilliant.org/wiki/derivative-by-first-principle/

Answer (score 1):

I guess that is because you use the derivative definition for a single variable function. However, the function f(x+h) the way you plug in becomes a two-variable function, so you cannot apply the definition here.

Actually, you can write this formula for f(x+h) only if h was some constant number, but in that case, it would not be the same h that is in a formula cause it is clearly not a constant value.